# How can I set detailTextLabel.text in static UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to set the Right Detail of a cell in a UITableView programmatically using Swift 3.

However, I'm unable to call the `detailTextLabel.text` to set it.

---

Currently, I have this screen. As seen, I need to set `Signed in as:` programmatically using a `UserDefaults` value.

[image: Image 1]

---

I've also set the Identifier of the cell:

[image: Image 2]

This is what I have tried:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "user_Cell", for: indexPath)

    let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let user = prefs.value(forKey: "USER") as? String

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user

    return cell
}
```

However, it returns an error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UITableView.m:6600
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier user_Cell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Define "totally wrong".

Comment: @rmaddy I've updated my question with the error I received

Comment: Have you searched on that error? It's been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: @rmaddy The problem is that it's a static table and he's trying to treat it here as a dynamic table. There are no prototype cells; the table is static.

Comment: @matt Thanks! So, it'll work if I change it to 'Dynamic Prototype'?

Comment: No, if you do that you'll have to rewrite the whole app.

Comment: Added "static" to your title just to help others find this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a static table. Modifying a cell works differently for a static table. You have to implement `cellForRowAt:` and call `super` and return the resulting `cell`. If this is the one special cell you want to modify, modify it (using the `indexPath` as a test). Like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    if indexPath == IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) { // double-check this
        let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
        if let user = prefs.value(forKey: "USER") as? String {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Good, I'm glad you figured out what I meant. :)